# Sync web directories between load balanced servers

Tags: filesystems, load-balancing, rsync

I have two load balanced servers each running exactly the same copy of various PHP based websites.

An admin user (or multiple admin users) hitting their site might therefore hit one or other of the servers when wanting to change content e.g. upload an image, delete a file from a media library, etc.

These operations mean one or other or both the servers go out of sync with each other and need to be brought back into line.

Currently I'm looking at rsync for this with the --delete option but am unsure how it reacts to files being deleted vs. new files being created between servers.

i.e. if I delete a file on server Server A and rsync with Server B the file should also be deleted from Server B (as it no longer exists on A) BUT If I separately upload a file to Server B as well as deleting a file from Server A before running the sync, will the file that got uploaded to Server B also get removed as it doesn't exist on Server A?

A number of tutorials on the web deal with a Master-Slave type scenario where Server B is a Mirror of Server A and this process just works, but in my situation both servers are effectively Masters mirroring each other.

I *think* rsync keeps a local history of files it's dealing with and as such may be able to deal with this problem gracefully but am not sure if this is really the case, or if it's dangerous to rely on this alone?

Is there a better way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: Say you have the following scenario:  Server A has files {A,B), Server B has files {B,C}.  If you run the sync on Server A, how do you know if file A should be deleted or sent to server B?  How would you determine weather or not file A was just added on Server A, or just deleted on Server B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't happy with my previous answer. Sounds too much like somebody must have invented a way to do this already.

It seems that there is! Check out [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). There's a GUI for it and everything.

Comment: We moved from rsync to unison before I saw your response, and it certainly does do what we need it too - seemingly reliably so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're doing a bidirectional rsync (i.e. running it first one way, and then the other) then you need to be using `--update`, and you need to have the clocks on both servers precisely aligned. If both servers write to the same file, the last write wins, and the earlier write is lost.

Second, I don't think you *can* use delete. Not directly anyway. The only state that rsync keeps is the state of the filesystem itself, and if that's a moving target then it'll get confused.

I suggest that when you delete a file you write its name to a file. Then, *instead* of using `rsync --delete`, do it manually with, for example, `cat deleted-files | ssh serverb xargs rm -v`.

So, your process would look something like this:

```
ServerA:
rsync  -a --update mydir serverB:mydir
cat deleted-files | ssh serverB xargs rm -v

ServerB:
rsync  -a --update mydir serverA:mydir
cat deleted-files | ssh serverA xargs rm -v
```

Obviously, the two syncs can't run at the same time, and I've left off other important rsync options: you probably want to consider `--delay-updates`, `--partial-dir` and others.